# How to force use of StringBuffer instead of StringBuilder by default in javac?

Tags: javac, stringbuilder, kvm, cldc, stringbuffer

I am trying to compile the CLDC with kvm on linux, I get an error

> cannot access java.lang.StringBuilder class file for java.lang.StringBuilder not found

at the statement:

```
return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
```

I think that is because this uses its own bootclasspath which contains `StringBuffer` but not `StringBuilder`. Now, how do I force javac to use `StringBuffer` instead of default `StringBuilder`?

My dev environment is:
Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS + javac 1.6.0_24 (sun-java6-jdk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After googling around a bit more, I found that one can set the target jsr specification with '-target' option to javac. To fix my problem , I had to go back to jsr14 to emit StringBuffer instead of StringBuilder.

javac  -target jsr14 *.java

More about this here: http://twit88.com/blog/2008/08/26/java-understanding-jsr14/

Answer (score 2):

You could try setting the source and object levels to 1.3 or whatever versin was the last one without StringBuilder.

Comment: thank you :), I wasn't sure of the exact option, found it after googling as '-target'.